# Thrown object copy constructs -- why?

Tags: c++, exception

I want to be able to throw a constructed object, but modify it just before it's thrown
(using the [Named Parameter Idiom](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.20)).
Given:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;

struct my_exception : std::exception { 
  my_exception() { 
    cout << "my_exception(): this=" << hex << (unsigned long)this << endl;
  }

  my_exception( my_exception const& ) { 
    cout << "my_exception( my_exception const& )" << endl;
  }

  ~my_exception() throw() { 
    cout << "~my_exception()" << endl;
  }

  my_exception& tweak() { 
    return *this;
  }

  char const* what() const throw() { return "my_exception"; }
};

int main() {
  try {
    throw my_exception().tweak();
  }
  catch ( my_exception const &e ) { 
    cout << "&e=" << hex << (unsigned long)&e << endl;
  }
}
```

When I run the program, I get:

```
my_exception(): this=7fff5fbfeae0
my_exception( my_exception const& )
~my_exception()
&e=1001000f0
~my_exception()
```

As you can see, the exception object caught is not the one that's originally thrown.
If I remove the call to `tweak()`, I instead get:

```
my_exception(): this=1001000f0
&e=1001000f0
~my_exception()
```

For the case where `tweak()` is called, why is the copy constructor called?  I want `tweak()` to operate on the originally constructed object and no copy to be made.  Is there any way to prevent the copy construction?

FYI: I'm using g++ 4.2.1 (part of Xcode on Mac OS X).

Answer (score 5):

An exception is thrown by value. You can't throw a reference as a reference. When you try, the object gets copied (using the statically known type).

By the way, this one reason why it's a good idea to make exceptions cloneable, and to have virtual rethrower method.

**EDIT** (see comments): For example, it's Undefined Behavior to propagate an exception through a C callback. But if you have defined a suitable exception class then you can clone it, and in C++-land again up the call chain rethrow via virtual method.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: So how would you modify my example to use clone() and/or a virtual rethrower method?

Comment: @Paul: I wouldn't. But then, as I'm writing this you have not explained anything about what the `tweak` method of yours is meant to accomplish. Guessing wildly about that, that it's meant to do some extra initialization, a good approach would be to instead define a derived class and use that class in the `throw` statement. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Don't understand the need for a virtual re-thrower. If you catch by reference and use `throw;` to rethrow no further copies will be made once the implementation has squirreled away the exception.

Comment: I am inclined to upvote for the first line, but at the same time inclined to downvote for the second one. There are few cases where you actually want an exception to be `cloneable` and `rethrowable`. In the general case the rethrow can be trivially obtained by a `throw;` with no arguments in the exception handler, and there is no use for the `clone`. (The only case where those two would be required would be to catch in one thread and rethrow in another without c++0x support, but providing that as a general advice seems more confusing than helpful).

Comment: @Martin, @David: For example, it's Undefined Behavior to propagate an exception through a C callback. But you can clone it, and in C++-land again up the call chain rethrow via virtual rethrower. It did not enter my mind that this would not be obvious and well known to readers, sorry for not thinking; I'll amend the answer.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Alf's answer, the fact that you aren't getting a copy operation when you don't call `tweak()` is because the standard permits (but doesn't require) eliding calls to the copy constructor to create the temporary exception object.  From C++03 15.1/5 (Throwing an exception):

> If the use of the temporary object can
>   be eliminated without changing the
>   meaning of the program except for the
>   execution of constructors and
>   destructors associated with the use of
>   the temporary object (12.2), then the
>   exception in the handler can be
>   initialized directly with the argument
>   of the throw expression. When the
>   thrown object is a class object, and
>   the copy constructor used to
>   initialize the temporary copy is not
>   accessible, the program is ill-formed
>   (even when the temporary object could
>   otherwise be eliminated).

If you make the copy constructor private, gcc will give you an error (even though when the constructor is public it doesn't get called).  MSVC will not give an error, but it should I think.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the following happens in your line `throw my_exception().tweak();` :

new my_exception object is created (locally, on the stack), tweak() returns reference to this local object. Then, when you throw this reference, you go out of the scope and local object gets deleted. So, the implementation copies the class to dynamic memory to keep reference valid.

In the second case you throw it by value and it is allocated in dynamic memory at once.